# Sitecore: Caching by custom param in code behind?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

We are looking to enable caching in Sitecore 6 on a specific page, however, this page has an image set based on a random value - and as such, we actually need to cache each individually rendered page so that we can keep this "random" image.

Any suggestions? I figured that we would need to use sublayout params, but can not see how I can set this in the code behind to influence the caching behaviour.

Any way of directly manipulating the cache entry?

Regards,

Andy

Comment: Just to answer my own question!

The way I found to do this is to access the Sublayout from the UserControl by the following code:

    Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Sublayout sub = this.Parent as Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Sublayout;
    if (sub != null && sub.VaryByParm)
    {
      sub.Parameters = "Image=" + num;
    }

As long as your SubLayout has VaryByParam set, the parameter will be set, and then cached - perfect result.

Comment: I am looking to accomplish the same thing. My Sublayout in this case is a UserControl. I can access the Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Sublayout parameters from my code behind, like you mentioned. However, if you are setting the varying parameter in the code behind of the very page you are caching, how will that work? Won't the page get cached the first time it is hit? And then each subsequent request would never reach the code behind? In which case the varying parameter would never be set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an outer sublayout defined in Sitecore, e.g. MyComponent. In the code for that, statically bind an inner sublayout, eg. MyComponentInner and in the C# of the former, set the VaryByParms value to be a random number.